# implicit binding this for a inner function in callback(avoiding use "this"..)

Tags: javascript

Ok, I can't find a better and clearer title, but basically I've got this:

```
var obj = function () {
    return {
        hi: function (name) {
            console.log("HI! " + name);
        },
        fun1: (function (cllb, name) {
            //WRONG!! I'm binding the callback not the hi function
            var f = cllb.call(this, name)
        }).bind(this)
    }
}
```

I call `fun1` like this:

```
var q = new obj()
q.fun1(function () {
    hi("paco")
})
```

Notice how I use `hi("paco")` and not `this.hi("paco")`. I need to avoid the `this` inside the callback. I know that it's not the most pragmatic and logic way, but in my real code the reasons are more obvious. Is it possible to do it in Javascript?

Comment: Without `.bind(this)` if you run the function like `obj.fun1(f,x)` then `this` inside of `fun1` is `obj`. `this` depends on how you call the function. And you probably shouldn't be using `new`, otherwise you want a constructor.

Comment: You might better show us your real code if it provides reasons for not using `this`. In fact, you will always need to use some kind of property access, `hi` is not a variable. Either use `this.hi()` or `q.hi()`.

Comment: you have to use `this` to call `hi`

Comment: Can you have a return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the closest your gonna get.

```
function thing(){


    this.fun1 = function(cb){
        var b = 'this.'+cb();
        var c = new Function(b);
        c.call(this);
    };

}
var t = new thing();

thing.fun1(function(){
    return 'hi("paco");';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pass `hi` as argument to the callback, there is no way to just call `hi(..)`. JavaScript has a [**lexical scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping), and `hi` is not in the scope of the callback.

> Is it possible to do it in Javascript?"

The answer is simply **no**.